# react-native run-android fails with error

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

[image: getting the following errors when running the command: <code>react-native run-android</code>]

i'm getting the following errors in my console.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-video:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 5.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s 151 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 138 up-to-date
>   error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above
>   for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a
>   device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>   error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with
>   --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Others seem to have the same problem. Try looking in https://www.google.com/search?q=execution+failed+for+task+react-native-firebase

Comment: @Yossi, tried googling, did not got my solution. then only posted here

Comment: try running app using 'react-native run-android --no-jetifier'

Comment: @SandipSingh error: unknown option `--no-jetifier'

Answer (score -1):

Is your android device is connected. Check it with

```
adb devices
```

If no device name shows then, no device is connected, try to connect your device correctly and run

```
react-native run-android
```

and in different terminal run

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have connected my device with debugging mode enabled. anyway it is throwing error with  ':react-native-video:compileDebugJavaWithJavac', ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Comment: adb devices prints the following

List of devices attached
8745ce5 device